# Form Reset to block bots on Shopifty

Tags: forms, shopify

I have a shopify store and have recently had a lot of fake accounts made presumably by bots. They have real email addresses and made up names. I want to prevent our email address from being labeled spam, so would like to block them. I've read about 'honeypot' and such but am curious if this is a good idea/how to code it.

Adding a form field that is labelled "Human test" or something with a text field with placeholder that says "enter nothing" or "leave blank" and if a bot adds any text to the field it automatically resets the entire form. Thoughts?